# extras intent in broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I want to to know how to extras intent value in broadcast receiver onReceive method...

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")){
                Logger.debug("action: Package added");
                Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            }
     }
```

now I don't know different key value for this particular intent so please anybody help me how to find key value of intent in onReceive method...

Comment: Seems, your question isn't clear enough. Can you describe more precisely what you want to do?

Answer (score 2):

The `Intent` documentation (which contains the broadcast action descriptions) explains what extras you can expect in the OS broadcast Intents.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

In any case, you can always call `keySet()` on the extras `Bundle` and see what keys are included that you can use to retrieve the data.